# Web Services Single API or Multiple APIs in terms of Non – Functional Requirements

Tags: c#, json, web-services, rest

Apologize in advance,

The question is trivial but I had arguments on this subject with my client and I want to know the correct approach.

I am in the process of developing some banking web API(s) to be consumed by mobile apps RESTfully; Services such as, getting list of user’s banking accounts, account balance and transfer money and the like.

Is there any difference between the following patterns in terms of non – functional requirements such as performance, security, maintenance and other metrics if any?

**Pattern 1**:

Having a Request and Response structures

```
public class Request
{
    public string Command { get; set; }     // Request Identifier
    public string Args { get; set; }        // Request Argumnets
}

public class Respond
{
    public string Command { get; set; }     // Respond Identifier
    public string Results { get; set; }     // Respond Result(s)
}
```

And one single API as

```
public Respond Process(Request request) 
{
    // process request and produces respond
    switch(request.Command)
    {
        case “GetBalance”:
            return GetBalance(request.Args);
        case “TransferMoney”:
            return TransferMoney(request.Args);
        …
    }
}
```

**Pattern 2**:

Having multiple API(s), one API for each service

```
public BalanceResults GetBalance(BalanceArgs args) 
{
    // process args and produces results
}
public TransferResults TransferMoney(TransferArgs args) 
{
    // process args and produces results
}
…
```

**Please pay attention** to the fact that in **pattern 1**, string `Args` in `Request` is a JSON serialization of a JSON object as well as string `Results` in `Respond` structure.

For ex.

`request.Args` will be deserialized as `BalanceArgs`, `TransferArgs` and the like. Also `respond.Results` will be deserialized as `BalanceResults`, `TransferResults` and the like.

Appreciation for your guide

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about REST and not discussion endpoints or resources, which I find somewhat confusing. If you're trying to build a REST API, think in terms of the HTTP spec and RESTful principles, not in terms of C# methods.

Anyway, I would expect there to be two endpoints:

`/accounts
/transfers`

and two resource types: `Account` and `Transfer`. A client wishing to get a balance would `GET /accounts/{id}`. A client wishing to create a transfer would `POST /transfers` and get back a Location of `/transfers/{id}`. The resources would have the germane properties - `Account` would have a balance property, and `Transfer` would have a current status property of some type.

Comment: Thanks in advance, so according to your answer, it is preferable to have multiple endpoints with simple in - out types rather than having one endpoint but with complex input and output types. Am i right? if that's what you mean, is there any difference between the two approaches in terms of performance and security?

Comment: @anonim In this case, yes. There are potential performance enhancements available with caching responses, either on the client or on the server with conditional requests. In theory, caching could be utilized with either of your approaches, but it will probably be messier. In terms of security, I see no difference unless you start including query parameters, which can get logged by intermediate servers and should not include any sensitive information.

Comment: please correct me if I am wrong. So according to what you said, the first approach; one endpoint with complex in - out types is better because it is possible to apply caching on it easier. If I am right, would you please provide me some references to that subject. Thanks for your kind help.